# Will Mir support workspaces?

Tags: xorg, workspaces, mir

Although the Workspace Switcher no longer appears by default in Raring/Saucy, it can still be enabled, and some users find it invaluable.

Will 14.04 or whichever version adopts Mir provide equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes. it's in the mir blueprint.
see https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1404-mir-converged